# What database should I use for a Flutter Application?

Tags: database, flutter, dart, backend

I am making an application in Flutter which is like an online market where users can login and post things to sell. The users can add photos to their announcements so there will be probably a lot of pictures that need to be stored.

It's my first time working with an online database so I don't know which one to use. I looked over Firebase and Amplify but I'm not really sure about how the pricing works or which one would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase pricing can be intricate, especially as your app scales. However, for smaller projects, it may offer a generous free tier.

AWS services, including Amplify, can have a steeper learning curve compared to Firebase.
Also AWS has a pay-as-you-go pricing model, and costs can accumulate based on usage. However, they do offer a free tier with limited resources.

I would start with Firebase, and as your project grows, reassess your needs and scalability requirements.